# I cannot see the QR code needed to claim my new Toitbox

Tags: obsolete

The QR code on the e-ink display of my Toitbox is not visible, and therefore I cannot scan the QR code with my smart phone on the display to claim the Toitbox into my organization.

Another similar situation is that the QR code on the e-ink display is blurry and my phone will not recognize the image.

Answer (score 0):

Toitboxes arrive unclaimed with a QR code on the E-Ink display. How to claim a Toitbox is explained in [here](https://toitbox.io/start/index.html)

If the QR code is not visible, it is also possible to claim a Toitbox manually by using the hardware ID of the device, which can be found if you remove the lid on the back of the Toitbox.
The hardware ID is represented as a 36 characters UUID (32 hexadecimal characters and 4 hyphens).

Read a description of how to manually claim a Toitbox [here](https://docs.toit.io/gettingstarted/claimtoitbox/#claiming-manually)

Navigate to the remote Toit Console, select the 'Claim device' menu item. In the claim dialog, type the hardware ID of the Toitbox, and click 'Claim'.